# Boost custom validator for std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, validation, c++11, boost

I have written the following custom validator for `std::vector<double>`.

```
typedef vector<double> coordinate;
void validate(boost::any& v,
  const vector<string>& values,
  coordinate*, int) {
  std::cout << "Custom validator called\n";
  coordinate c;
  vector<double> dvalues;
  for(vector<string>::const_iterator it = values.begin();
    it != values.end();
    ++it) {
    stringstream ss(*it);
    copy(istream_iterator<double>(ss), istream_iterator<double>(),
      back_inserter(dvalues));
    if(!ss.eof()) {
      std::cerr << "SS EOF\n";
      throw po::invalid_option_value("Invalid coordinate specification sseof");
    }
  }
  if(dvalues.size() != 2) {
    std::cerr << "dvalues size\n";
    throw po::invalid_option_value("Invalid coordinate specification dvalues size");
  }
  c.push_back(dvalues[0]);
  c.push_back(dvalues[1]);
  v = c;
}
```

And I add options in the following manner:

```
coordinate c;
// Setup options.
po::options_description desc("Options");
desc.add_options()
  ("instruments.prop", po::value<coordinate>( &c )->multitoken(),
   "plugin names" );
```

The custom validator is not being used by the program at all. I don't get the message "Custom validator called" which should have been printed if my validator was being used. Instead I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  the argument ('1 2.9') for option 'instruments.name' is invalid Aborted (core dumped)

My config file looks like:

[instruments]
prop= 1 2.9

Any ideas on how to parse multiple arguments from config file without writing them in separate lines like this:

[instruments]
prop = 1
prop = 2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd write a custom conversion instead:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfcdcebe640b4fe1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
typedef std::vector<double> coordinate;

int main() {
    coordinate c;

    // Setup options.
    po::options_description desc("Options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("instruments.prop", po::value<std::string>()->multitoken()->notifier([&c](std::string const& v) {
             auto it = boost::make_split_iterator(v, boost::token_finder(boost::algorithm::is_any_of(" ,")));
             std::transform(it, {}, back_inserter(c), [](auto& s) {
                        return boost::lexical_cast<double>(s);
                     });
         }),
         "plugin names" );

    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    po::variables_map vm;
    store(po::parse_config_file(ifs, desc, false), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout << "c: ", " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
c: 1 2.9
```